# How can I run tests in a browser context along side my regular tests that use a Selenium framework and Mocha?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, selenium, phantomjs, mocha.js

I'm using [Nemo](https://github.com/paypal/nemo) to run Selenium tests in Mocha, which works nicely because Nemo just works as a module that I import into my tests and can run just doing

```
mocha tests/*.js
```

But I have some functions that I'd like to unit test along side my Selenium tests that use DOM functions like document.createElement, so I need to run them in a browser context. I looked into using PhantomJS for this, but I couldn't find any answers that used PhantomJS as a module (like Nemo), and instead required you to do something like

```
phantomjs tests/*.js
```

Is there any way to import Phantom into my regular tests and just use it as a module instead of on the command line? Or maybe I'm just approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Innately, PhantomJS does not offer a way to require it as a module (as you can also find in the [FAQ](http://phantomjs.org/faq.html)).

---

Indeed, there is an node module called [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node), which will create a bridge between phantomjs and your unit tests.

This module will basically spawn an phantomjs instance, execute your test and pass the results to your unit test, so you can assert them.